# Flutter execute a function when a value of a variable changes

Tags: flutter, dart

Am new to flutter and in my widget i have an integer that i would like to execute a function when its value is changed.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   
  class TestPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    const TestPageWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

    @override
   _TestPageWidgetState createState() => _TestPageWidgetState();
    }

  class _TestPageWidgetState extends State<TestPageWidget> {

   int myItem = 1; //listen changes to this and execute a function


   @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
   
    //change myItem value after 3 seconds
     Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
        myItem = 3;
    });
  }
   
  //something like this. Am not sure how i can listen for the change
  ValueNotifier(value) {
      print('Value as now changed'); //expected this to show after delay of 3 seconds
  }
}
```

AM changing the value in the  initstate and using ValueNotifier to check if it has changed but it never prints even after change. Is there a way i can watch for myItem value and execute a function if the value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement there is simple solution without `ValueNotifier`. ValueNotifier is more suitable when you want to refresh a widget when a value changes

```
class _TestPageWidgetState extends State<TestPageWidget> {
  int myItem = 0; //listen changes to this and execute a function

  void setItem(int itemValue) {
    this.myItem = itemValue;
    this.itemChanged();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //change myItem value after 3 seconds
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      setItem(3);
    });
  }

  void itemChanged() {
    print(this.myItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without calling a method when setting the value. That is to just listen for the changes especially if you want to watch for changes in a child widget passed from parent widget.

Comment: then its better to go with ValueNotifier. check this sample code https://gist.github.com/psovit/59fb58ed79728ff16af3b248264a55ae. change ValueNotifier type to int like ValueNotifier<int>

Comment: there are different approaches available related to  listing to a parent widget changes. This is a big area. better check the official documentation to get an idea https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt